# Weird metal sound when accelerating from 0 MPH (with recording)

Tags: automatic-transmission, noise

It's hard to describe the sound so it will be easier if you give it a [listen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GNQ-WH5NN0). Note that in that video I thought the problem was the brakes but now I think it might be something to do with the transmission since it happens at a stop, but goes away if I shift into neutral.

I just changed the filter and put in 5 quarts of new fluid. It's got the right amount of fluid in it, not too much and not too little.

The sound is not as bad if I accelerate slowly. If I press hard on the accelerator or start on an incline the sound is pretty bad.

The truck is running a little rough and will stall if you leave it sit but I think that's because it has old gas in it. It runs like a normal car on the freeway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is not your brakes. In your video, the sound appears when the car is stopped. This means the brakes were working to hold the car in place. You said "if you shift into neutral the sound goes away", assuming you were still holding the brakes, it indicates it isn't the brakes.

What you are describing could be any number of things. It sounds like something vibrating against the body or frame which transfers audible sound to the interior of the car. It could be anything...bad motor mount, loose exhaust pipe, rough running engine, transmission mount, etc.

Bad gas will make an engine run rough and this can cause all kinds of vibration which can be converted to audible sounds throughout the vehicle.

Comment: I had a friend look at it yesterday. The sound appeared to be coming from the front passenger side tire. It stops making the sound if while your foot is on the brake you press down on the parking brake and then release the regular brake. My friend thinks it is just a loose wheel bearing. Assuming it's not because my engine is running rough because of the bad gas do you think that's a reasonable guess?

Comment: Have no idea what the make and model is, so everything is a guess. Please see my edit.

Comment: 99 ranger v6 3L. Thanks for the advice. I'm going for the wheel bearing next. Will update post with how that goes. Hopefully I'm not wasting my time...

Comment: Think about it. Bearings will not make sound while they are stationary. When the car is stopped, what components ***are*** still moving (able to make noise)?

Comment: The crankshaft and flywheel? The brake pump? It doesn't sound like it's coming from the transmission. It sounds like it's a little to the right and in front of the transmission.

Comment: It was the transmission mount. There are two bolts that hold it to the cross-member and only one was in. As a bonus putting the other bolt in also lifted up the exhaust which looked suspiciously low but it wasn't clear why.